# A confusing Exception：ClassCastException

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, parent

`InsertPanel` extends `JPanel`,I add it into a `JFrame`(my main frame).
I want to create a `JDialog` ,give my main frame to its constructor to be its father frame,
Doesn't `InsertPanel.this.getParent()` return a `JFrame`?

why it give me a `ClassCastException`?

```
eclipse said:Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JPanel cannot be cast to javax.swing.JFrame
```

my code:

```
    createClassButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            new CreateClassDialog((JFrame) InsertPanel.this.getParent());
        }
    });
```

thanks!!!

Comment: please what do you really want to do with this code line, for better help sooner edit your question with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 3):

Adding a `Component` to a `JFrame` adds it to the content pane of the `JFrame` which can be any `Container`. In your case it seems to be a `JPanel`. As a result, the parent is not the `JFrame` as you expect

Answer (score 3):

What if you use method of the panel? `public Container getTopLevelAncestor()`

Answer (score 2):

As can be clearly seen from the message of the exception: no, your specific `InsertPanel.this.getParent()` does not return a `JFrame`, it returns a `JPanel`. (This is because `JFrame`s also has internal window management and layers and stuff so the parent of your panel is just some other panel. Somewhere in the chain you will find the `JFrame`, though.) You should find another way to hand in your frame to the dialog.

Comment: That other way would be SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(InsertPanel.this)